# Printing a Vaadin Layout

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, vaadin

I want to print a Vaadin layout and all of its components (text, tables, html, charts, etc), sending it to a pdf preview, hopefully getting exactly what I see in the screen (for that specific layout)

thanks!!!

Comment: you could print the page?

Comment: Thanks for your answer luuksen....I can print the whole page and of course is not just as I see it, but it does work...now I want to print a specific layout of that page and make it fit in a pdf...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, seems to me, that is not something Vaadin is able to provide. You have to extract the html specific to you desired layout and, along with the styling, delegate to a tool that might convert it properly to a PDF, like [jsPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf), but you need to integrate it into your Vaadin application.

If you're interested I can try to write some code that will help you. If so, let me know.